# Эффект фонарика

Tags: анимация, jquery, javascript, эффекты

Никак не могу найти в интернете никаких решений с эффектами освещения, лампы, фонарика. Очень нужно подобное для проекта, есть у кого что на примете?

Answer (score 7):

Эм... ну вот: [Dynamic PNG shadow position & opacity with jQuery](http://pushingpixels.at/experiments/dynamic_shadow/). Слева выключатель лампочки. Лампочку водите и тень меняется :)

**UPD1.** Не совсем понимаю что такое фонарик, но вот: [jQuery PlugIn : Spot](http://spotlightdemo.blogspot.ru/)

Comment: круто) (10 символов)

Comment: Спасибо) Хороший эффект тени, но мне нужен фонарик